# Assigning 20 Apples to 3 Baskets

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion, balls-in-bins

I have put together a summary of the possible ways with assigning 20 Apples to 3 Baskets, I am wondering are my solutions correct? I know a couple might be wrong as I didn't use inclusion exclusion principle:

1. Indistinguishable Apples:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 20 \rightarrow \dbinom{22}{20}$$

2. Distinguishable Apples:

$$3^{20}$$

3. Basket $1 (B_1)$ $\leq$ 5:

- Indistinguishable Apples:

$$x1' + x2' + x3' = 14 => \dbinom{22}{20} - \dbinom{16}{14}$$
Question Here: suppose B1 <= 1, B2 <= 1, B3 <= 1
I also got: $x1' + x2' + x3' = 14$ => $\dbinom{22}{20} - \dbinom{16}{14}$  Same as just B1 <= 5?
But shouldn't this be $\dbinom{20}{3}$ ? from the pov of basket
Or $3*2*1=3!$ from pov of apples? I thought this will reduce into binomial theorem n choose k, since unordered with replacement but constrained to less than or equal to 1. I tried with example of choosing 3 object from 5 object using x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 +x5 = 3 and apply constraint of <= 1, I got negative on RHS. And this certainly doesn't equal $\dbinom{5}{3}$ ?!

- Distinguishable Apples:

  $$2^{20} + \dbinom{20}{1}2^{19} + \dbinom{20}{2}2^{18} + \dbinom{20}{3}2^{17} + \dbinom{20}{4}2^{16} + \dbinom{20}{5}2^{15}$$

4. Basket 1 (B1) >= 5:

- Indistinguishable Apples:

  $$x1' + x2' + x3' = 15 => \dbinom{17}{15}$$
- Distinguishable Apples:

  $$\dbinom{20}{5}3^{15}$$

5. B1 <= 5, B2 <= 3:

- Indistinguishable Apples:

  $$x1' + x2' + x3' = 10 => \dbinom{22}{20} - \dbinom{12}{10}$$
- Distinguishable Apples:

  The cartesian product of sets: |{0,1,2,3,4,5}$\times${0,1,2,3}| = 24

  $$\dbinom{20}{0}\dbinom{20}{0}  + \dbinom{20}{0}\dbinom{20}{1}  + \dbinom{20}{0} \dbinom{20}{2}  ... + \dbinom{20}{1} \dbinom{19}{0}  + \dbinom{20}{1}\dbinom{19}{1}  + \dbinom{20}{1}\dbinom{19}{2}  + ...$$ to all 24 ways

6. B1 >= 5, B2 >= 3:

- Indistinguishable Apples:

  $$x1' + x2' + x3' = 12 => \dbinom{14}{12} $$
- Distinguishable Apples:

$$\dbinom{20}{5}\dbinom{15}{3} *3^{12}$$

I am hoping for distinguishable apples case of 4 and 6, I don't need to do calculation for each permutation, and just do a single calculation like above. What happens when both apples and baskets become in distinguishable? and basket becomes indistinguishable and apple distinguishable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: ok thanks just updated the format

Comment: Number $5$ is wrong for the indistinguishable case.  You have to use inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: Yes and for 4 and 6's distinguishable case, are they wrong as well? I might need to sum up individual combinations like 3 and 5's distinguishable case.

Comment: Yes in the distinguishable case of both $4$ and $6$ you've got a lot of double counting.

Comment: intuitively why there are double counting for 4 and 6 ?

Comment: You can obtain $\implies$ by typing `$\implies$`, $\leq$ by typing `$\leq$`, and $\geq$ by typing `$\geq$`.

Comment: @JerryH is there somewhere you did not understand  in my solution ? You did not show any reaction yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my first glance , you have problem with distinguishable apple to distinguishable baskets in question $4$ and $6$.

The most suitable ways for distinguishable objects into distinguishable boxes is exponential generating functions , they prevent you to overcounting.

Lets firtly check over the fourth question , we see that you are making overcounting when the apples are distinguishable. If the first basket will have more than or equal to $5$ , then the exponential generating function for it must be $$\frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^7}{7!}+...$$

There is not any restriction for the others , so their exponential generating functions must be $$\bigg(1+\frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+...\bigg)$$

As a result , we should the coefficient of $\frac{x^{20}}{20!}$ or find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ and multiply it by $20!$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(\frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^7}{7!}+...\bigg) \times \bigg(1+\frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+...\bigg)^2 $$

When we comes to sixth question , the expoenetial generating functions :

For first basket :  $$\bigg(\frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^7}{7!}+...\bigg)$$

For second basket :  $$\bigg(\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+...\bigg)$$

For third basket : $$\bigg(1+\frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+...\bigg)$$

As a result , we should the coefficient of $\frac{x^{20}}{20!}$ or find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ and multiply it by $20!$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(\frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^7}{7!}+...\bigg) \times \bigg(\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}+...\bigg) \times \bigg(1+\frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!}+...\bigg)  $$

Comment: Firstly* not firtly *

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @JerryH you are welcome !